# How do I get the extensions that are installed remotely on Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I was trying to get all the extensions installed on the machine. Now in windows with wsl2 enabled you can install the extensions either in the local (windows 10) or remote (ubuntu wsl2).

When I run `code --list-extensions` in powershell it only shows the extensions installed in the local only. And when I run `code --list-extensions` in the ubuntu-wsl2 it shows that the options is not supported.

My question is how can I get the extensions installed in the remote environment?